# jQuery Set Focus After Tab Key Press

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the focus to a particular text box after pressing the TAB key.  There is only one text box on the page.  It seems pretty simple.

```
$("#status").keydown(function (e) {    
    if (e.which == 9) {
        $("#statuses").html(this.value);        
        this.value = "";        
        $("#status").focus();
    }
});
```

Here is my jsFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7Rfqa/

If I code it for the ENTER button it works fine, but for TAB it just goes to the URL bar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to stop the default behavior, try this

```
$("#status").keydown(function (e) {    
  if (e.which == 9) {
    $("#statuses").html(this.value);        
    this.value = "";        
    $("#status").focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Rfqa/1/

Comment: Thanks, that got it!  I can go home now :)

Comment: Thank you  – Hattan Shobokshi