# Row wise tabindex lost focus after few continuous tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have an ui-grid with just 1 column and about 1000 rows. Each row have a textbox in it. I want to navigate through textbox by tab. This works fine about 10 - 15 rows, after that the textbox is losing its focus, then if you press tab again, it will skip next few rows and jump to a further textbox.

See the issue [plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/N4iT2Vo5CV2gs2I7jxiA?p=preview)

UI-Grid options:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    rowHeight: '200',
    enableColumnMenus: false,
    paginationPageSize: 2000,
    columnDefs: [
      {name:"value", width:'*',
        cellTemplate: gridTemplate,
      }
    ],
    data: gridData
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why this behavior happens:

`ui.grid` has his own `ui.grid.infiniteScroll` module however by default it doesn't render all your 1000 items because of performance penalty.

If you will inspect DOM structure of the table you will find that `ui.grid` renders 15 items only and udates it on scrolling (scroll triggers also on tab click). This is a reason why 1st 15 items work properly with focus on tab click.

[image]

When you reach index 16,  `ui.grid` **re-render 15 items with new indexes and therefore you lose the focus.**

I saw you opened also this issue on [github/issues](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/6411) and I believe its `ui.grid` bug in addition to 1479 others :).

From history `ui.grid` has about 200 issues related to focus and it looks like their developers don't hurry up to fix them because its too complicated and can cause to regression.

So my conclusion is just to live with it or use pagination structure.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever @Maxim mentioned is absolutely true. To get rid of this issue, 
what you can do as workaround is set virtualThreshold = 50 and than use pagination, so that focused is not lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack your way around it by catching the TAB key press event, and override the default behavior.

Each textbox will listen on key-press event, passing focus to the next textbox.

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21009184/6767060) that can help.

However, 1000 inputs sounds like a bad UX, and probably will have bad performance.